# Address Book framework, app freezes while saving

Tags: ios, xcode, abaddressbook, ios7.1

I am writing an app for editing address book group, it is running a lot of changes like remove all contact from book, add all contacts, etc. The problem is that when the methods are running the app freezes UI, I understand that it happens because of running in the main thread but when I am trying to do it in background, it has problems like crashing and wrong changes in the group. Who can help me with resolving that issue?

I think running that in for a lot of times is blocking my UI:

```
ABAddressBookSave(_addressBookRef, &cfError);
```

Answer (score 0):

**First solution:**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 
                                         (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
   <Write your method here>
});
```

**Second solution:**

```
- (void)syncPersonOutOfAddressBook
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(syncContactsThread) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

-(void)syncContactsThread{
    if([self getAccessPermission]){
        ABAddressBookRef addressBook;
        CFErrorRef error = nil;
        addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL,&error);
        [self AddressBookUpdated:addressBook]; //this is method is to get address from device
    }

}
```

For more information [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552545/how-to-get-phonebook-contacts-from-ios-device).